# Выбрать из 4-х массивов по элементу с минимальной разницей между наибольшим и наименьшим из них

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Даны 4 массива, надо выбрать из каждого из них по одному числу x_i, чтобы разница между x_min и x_max (наиб. и наим. среди 4х выбранных элементов x_i) была минимальной. Если таких наборов несколько, можно использовать любой из них.

Сложности возникли не с реализацией, а с созданием алгоритма. Я хотел использовать жадный алгоритм, но не могу понять, как может помочь для получения ответа решение подзадач для двух массивов.

UPD : Написал алгоритм, работает верно, но не проходит по времени. Не из-за того-ли что я вынес поиск ближайшего элемента в отдельную функцию dist и вызываю ее потом по три раза на каждую группу?

```
int dist(const std::vector<int>& A, int x) {
    int sec = binary_search(A, x), ans;
    if (sec == 0) {
        ans = 0;
    } else if (sec == A.size()) {
        ans = sec - 1;
    } else if ((abs(A[sec] - x) < abs(A[sec - 1] - x))) {
        ans = sec;
    } else {
        ans = sec - 1;
    }
    return ans;
}

int diff(const std::vector<int>& A) {
    return *std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end()) - *std::min_element(A.begin(), A.end());
}
int main() {
    // здесь считываю, сортирую вектора.
    std::vector<int> ans(4);
    int min = 100000000000;
    for (int i = 0; i != n1; i++) { //прохожусь по первому
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= 2; ++i2) { //рассматриваю 2^3  смежных случаев
            for (int i3 = 0; i3 <= 2; ++i3) {
                for (int i4 = 0; i4 <= 2; ++i4) {
                    std::vector<int> temp(4);
                temp[0] = v1[i];
                //здесь рассматриваю случаи, чтобы не было выходов за вектор
                temp[1] = v2[i_2 - 1 + dist(v2, v1[i])];
                temp[2] = v3[i_3 - 1 + dist(v3, v1[i])];
                temp[3] = v4[i_4 - 1 + dist(v4, v1[i])];
                if (diff(temp) < min) {
                    min = diff(temp);
                    ans = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
for (auto elem : ans) {
    std::cout << elem << " ";
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Наибольший и найменьший среди кого, среди всех массивов?

Comment: Выглядит как чисто алгоритмическая задача. Вам к математикам, а не сюда.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните что вам не понятно про решение для двух массивов.

Comment: @Cerbo наиб. и наим. среди 4х выбранных элементов x_i.

Comment: Алгоритм для двух массивов понятен, но не понятно, как он поможет решить задачу для четырех.

Comment: @Parket Пожалуйста конкретней, что не понятно? Приведите свое решение например.

Comment: @Cerbo, для двух я делал так - для каждого элемента первого считал разность с каждым элементом из второго и тем самым находил два элемента с минимальной разностью. Но если возьмем такие массивы {1, 7} {8, 10}, {0}, то решение для первых двух массивов (7, 8) в общем решении никак не пригодится, оно будет такое - 0, 1, 8.

Comment: @Parket, добавьте это описание в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, должна сработать следующая идея: вы просто обобщаете алгоритм для двух массивов на более общий случай.

Например, так:

1. Сортируете все массивы.
2. Проходитесь по первому массиву. Запоминаете текущий индекс 0 во всех 4 массивах.
3. На каждом шагу, продвигаете индекс в первом массиве, и находите ближайший элемент к нему во остальных массиве. Для этого вам придётся продвинуться вперёд в этих массивах. При этом вы получаете для каждого из массивов ближайший элемент к элементу первого массива.

   - На этом шаге мы ищем группу элементов с оптимальным расстоянием между ними, которая *включает данный элемент первого массива*.
   - Это ещё не гарантирует, что мы нашли оптимум. Нам нужно перебрать 2^3 вариантов из { «ближайший снизу», «ближайший сверху» } для каждого из массивов, каждый из них может дать оптимум.
4. Находите расстояние между наибольшим и наименьшим из них. Сравниваете его с текущим максимумом и продвигаетесь дальше по первому массиву.

Мы проходимся по каждому из массивов один раз, общая асимптотика — сумма длин массивов.

Comment: Можете посмотреть алгоритм, у него та же асимптотика, что и у вас?

Comment: @Parket: Не, у вас вызывается двоичный поиск на каждый элемент, то есть по асимптотике n log n. У меня вроде без логарифма. Трюк в том, что вам не обязательно искать соответствующие элементы в других массивах, вы можете просто «прошагать» от предыдущего найденного элемента.

Comment: А как при "прошагивании" находить ближайший элемент к элементу первого массива? И в какой части программы это надо реализовывать?

Comment: @Parket: Ну, когда вы переходите к следующему элементу в первом массиве, вам нужно найти позиции ближайших к нему в остальных массивах. Но ваш код помнит ближайшие позиции для предыдущего элемента (найдены на предыдущей итерации), и идёте от них вперёд до тех пор, пока не найдёте элемент >= текущего элемента 1-го массива.

Comment: @минусатор: Хотелось бы услышать вашу критику.

Comment: Я не минусатор:). Но при таком подходе непонятно, каким образом будут отслежены все возможные комбинации. На мой взгляд, требуется жёстко фиксировать адрес минимального (или максимального) элемента, чтобы считать в одну сторону.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Жёстко фиксировать не обязательно, достаточно одного шага вверх и одного вниз. (Если я правильно понял, что вы имеете в виду под «максимальным» элементом, такого термина в моём ответе нету.)

Comment: А как тогда контролировать разность между крайними элементами в выборке?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Вы не могли бы объяснить вашу мысль немного яснее? Что вы называете максимальным элементом, и что такое «контроль» разности?

Comment: Попробую. Наша цель - собрать группу (выборку по одному элементу из каждого массива, имеющую наименьший разброс (разность наибольшего и наименьшего значения в группе). Если бы мы заранее знали, какой элемент и из какого массива будет минимальным, то алгоритм поиска оптимальной группы стал бы простым и скучным. Мы этого не знаем, но можем решить вопрос путём перебора всех вариантов, для минимального элемента. Т.е. смысл в том, чтобы точно знать: в соседних массивах ищутся соседние **справа** варианты. В то же время вариант с промежуточным и ближайшими к нему элементами выглядит сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**
Возможна реализация алгоритма для произвольного количества массивов **k**.
Минимальный элемент искомой группы может оказаться в любом из массивов.
Вычисляя ближайший сверху элемент в каждом из оставшихся **k-1** массивов и сравнивая полученную разницу с минимально достигнутой, можно вовремя прекратить перебор.

Для случая целых элементов можно подготовить массивы гистограмм,  в которых каждому ключу соответствует индекс последнего элемента в отсортированном массиве, не превосходящего этот ключ. Это снижает сложность поиска до **O(1)**.

Поскольку перебираются не все из оставшихся **k-1** массивов, то вычислительная сложность алгоритма равна **o(k<sup>2</sup>n)**, где **n** - размерность массивов, что сопоставимо с затратами на сортировку исходных массивов.

Время работы программы для **k=8, n=100000** составило 28 с.

Программа на PHP:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
set_time_limit(300);

define("LB", 10000);
define("HB", 99999);
define("ARR_CNT", 4);
define("ARR_DIM", 10);
define("PR", 1);

// Вывод одномерного массива
function print_1d($text, $v){
    $eps = 1e-7;
    print "$text"."[";
    $cnt = -1;
    foreach($v as $key => $item){
        if(++$cnt) print ",&emsp;";
        $flag = true;
        if($cnt && !($cnt%10)) print"<br>";
        print "&quot;$key&quot;=>";
        if(abs((int)$item - $item) > $eps){
            printf("%.3f", $item);
        }else{
            print $item;
        }
    } 
    print "], ";
}

// Вывод двумерного массива
function print_2d($text, $v, $print_key = true, $glue = ""){
    print "$text"."[$glue";
    foreach($v as $key => $item){
        print "&emsp;";
        if($print_key) print "$key => ";
        print_1d("", $item);
        print "$glue";
    } 
    print "], ";
}

// Заполнение группы ближайшими сверху элементами
function fill_group($arr, $gist, &$group, $delta){
    $cnt = count($arr);                 // количество массивов
    reset($group);
    $min_item = each($group);
    $min_key = $min_item["key"];
    $min_val = end($min_item["value"]);
    $d = 0;
    foreach($arr as $sub_key => $sub){
        if($sub_key == $min_key){   // минимум уже в группе
            continue;
        }
        if(array_key_exists($min_val, $gist[$sub_key])){
            $key = $gist[$sub_key][$min_val];   // $sub[$key] <= $min_val <= $sub[$key+1]
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        if(($val = $sub[++$key]) < $min_val){
            return false;
        }
        if(($sub_val = $val - $min_val) >= $delta){ // разность больше оптимального разброса
            if(PR > 0){
                $group[$sub_key] = [$key => $val];
                print_2d("<br>group = ", $group);
                print "&emsp;Разность = $sub_val >= $delta";
            }
            return false;
        }elseif($sub_val > $d){ // разность больше текущей  
            $d = $sub_val;
        }
        $group[$sub_key] = [$key => $val];
    }
    return $d;
}

// Вычисление группы элементов из разных подмассивов, имеющей наименьший разброс
function near($arr, $gist, $delta){
    $cnt = count($arr);
    $group_delta = [];  
    for($a = 0; $a < $cnt-1; $a++){
        foreach($arr[$a] as $keya => $vala){
            $group = [];
            $group[$a] = [$keya => $vala];
            $d = fill_group($arr, $gist, $group, $delta);
            if($d !== false){
                print_2d("<br><br>Разброс: $d&emsp;Группа: ",$group);
                if(PR>1){
                    print "<br>";
                }
                $delta = $d;
                ksort($group);
                $group_delta = $group;
                if($delta == 0){
                    return[$delta, $group];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ksort($group_delta);
    return[$delta, $group_delta];
}

$arr = [];
for($a = 0; $a < ARR_CNT; $a++){
    $ar = [];
    for($v = 0; $v < ARR_DIM; $v++){
        $ar[] = mt_rand(LB, HB);
    }
    $arr[] = $ar;
}
if(PR > 0){
    print_2d("Исходные подмассивы:<br>", $arr, false, "<br>");
}

$time_start = microtime(true);
$cnt = count($arr);
$dim = count($arr[0]);
foreach($arr as &$ar) sort($ar);
if(PR > 0){
    print_2d("<br><br>Отсортированные подмассивы:<br>", $arr, false, "<br>");
}

$l = [];
$h = [];
foreach($arr as $sub){
    $l[] = reset($sub);
    $h[] = end($sub);
}
$lb = min($l);
$hb = max($h);
print("<br>Количество массивов: $cnt&emsp;Размерность массивов: $dim&emsp;Минимум = $lb&emsp;Максимум = $hb");
$gist = [];
for($key = 0; $key < $cnt; $key++){
    $gs = array_fill($lb-1, $hb+1, 0);
    foreach($arr[$key] as $item){
        $gs[$item] += 1;    
    }
    $sum = -1;
    foreach($gs as &$item){
        $sum += $item;
        $item = $sum;
    }
    $gist[$key] = $gs;
}
if(PR > 1){
    print_2d("<br>Гистограммы:<br>", $gist, false, "");
}   
print "<br><br>Поиск группы элементов из разных подмассивов, имеющей наименьший разброс:";
list($delta, $group) = near($arr, $gist, $hb-$lb);
$time = microtime(true) - $time_start;
print"<br><br>Время выполнения: $time с";
print_2d("<br><br>ОТВЕТ<br>Разброс = $delta<br>Группа: ", $group, true, "<br>");
```

Результаты для k=4, n=10 (принцип работы алгоритма):

```
Исходные подмассивы:
[
 ["0"=>46818, "1"=>88692, "2"=>93764, "3"=>84501, "4"=>22087, "5"=>59798, "6"=>60063, "7"=>93613, "8"=>26334, "9"=>12494], 
 ["0"=>13695, "1"=>59732, "2"=>41868, "3"=>64764, "4"=>17763, "5"=>30258, "6"=>18973, "7"=>40210, "8"=>25628, "9"=>81280], 
 ["0"=>20776, "1"=>82350, "2"=>85761, "3"=>17027, "4"=>45412, "5"=>73508, "6"=>75899, "7"=>87889, "8"=>98471, "9"=>95593], 
 ["0"=>74338, "1"=>12243, "2"=>60921, "3"=>69389, "4"=>77771, "5"=>34199, "6"=>82329, "7"=>32520, "8"=>87711, "9"=>29336], 
], 

Отсортированные подмассивы:
[
 ["0"=>12494, "1"=>22087, "2"=>26334, "3"=>46818, "4"=>59798, "5"=>60063, "6"=>84501, "7"=>88692, "8"=>93613, "9"=>93764], 
 ["0"=>13695, "1"=>17763, "2"=>18973, "3"=>25628, "4"=>30258, "5"=>40210, "6"=>41868, "7"=>59732, "8"=>64764, "9"=>81280], 
 ["0"=>17027, "1"=>20776, "2"=>45412, "3"=>73508, "4"=>75899, "5"=>82350, "6"=>85761, "7"=>87889, "8"=>95593, "9"=>98471], 
 ["0"=>12243, "1"=>29336, "2"=>32520, "3"=>34199, "4"=>60921, "5"=>69389, "6"=>74338, "7"=>77771, "8"=>82329, "9"=>87711], 
], 
Количество массивов: 4 Размерность массивов: 10 Минимум = 12243 Максимум = 98471

Поиск группы элементов из разных подмассивов, имеющей наименьший разброс:

Разброс: 16842 Группа: [ 0 => ["0"=>12494],  1 => ["0"=>13695],  2 => ["0"=>17027],  3 => ["1"=>29336], ], 
group = [ 0 => ["1"=>22087],  1 => ["3"=>25628],  2 => ["2"=>45412], ],  Разность = 23325 >= 16842
group = [ 0 => ["2"=>26334],  1 => ["4"=>30258],  2 => ["2"=>45412], ],  Разность = 19078 >= 16842
group = [ 0 => ["3"=>46818],  1 => ["7"=>59732],  2 => ["3"=>73508], ],  Разность = 26690 >= 16842

Разброс: 13710 Группа: [ 0 => ["4"=>59798],  1 => ["8"=>64764],  2 => ["3"=>73508],  3 => ["4"=>60921], ], 

Разброс: 13445 Группа: [ 0 => ["5"=>60063],  1 => ["8"=>64764],  2 => ["3"=>73508],  3 => ["4"=>60921], ], 
group = [ 1 => ["0"=>13695],  0 => ["1"=>22087],  2 => ["0"=>17027],  3 => ["1"=>29336], ],  Разность = 15641 >= 13445

Разброс: 11573 Группа: [ 1 => ["1"=>17763],  0 => ["1"=>22087],  2 => ["1"=>20776],  3 => ["1"=>29336], ], 

Разброс: 10363 Группа: [ 1 => ["2"=>18973],  0 => ["1"=>22087],  2 => ["1"=>20776],  3 => ["1"=>29336], ], 
group = [ 1 => ["3"=>25628],  0 => ["2"=>26334],  2 => ["2"=>45412], ],  Разность = 19784 >= 10363
group = [ 1 => ["4"=>30258],  0 => ["3"=>46818], ],  Разность = 16560 >= 10363
group = [ 1 => ["5"=>40210],  0 => ["3"=>46818],  2 => ["2"=>45412],  3 => ["4"=>60921], ],  Разность = 20711 >= 10363
group = [ 1 => ["6"=>41868],  0 => ["3"=>46818],  2 => ["2"=>45412],  3 => ["4"=>60921], ],  Разность = 19053 >= 10363
group = [ 1 => ["7"=>59732],  0 => ["4"=>59798],  2 => ["3"=>73508], ],  Разность = 13776 >= 10363
group = [ 1 => ["8"=>64764],  0 => ["6"=>84501], ],  Разность = 19737 >= 10363

Разброс: 3221 Группа: [ 1 => ["9"=>81280],  0 => ["6"=>84501],  2 => ["5"=>82350],  3 => ["8"=>82329], ], 
group = [ 2 => ["0"=>17027],  0 => ["1"=>22087], ],  Разность = 5060 >= 3221
group = [ 2 => ["1"=>20776],  0 => ["1"=>22087],  1 => ["3"=>25628], ],  Разность = 4852 >= 3221
group = [ 2 => ["2"=>45412],  0 => ["3"=>46818],  1 => ["7"=>59732], ],  Разность = 14320 >= 3221
group = [ 2 => ["3"=>73508],  0 => ["6"=>84501], ],  Разность = 10993 >= 3221
group = [ 2 => ["4"=>75899],  0 => ["6"=>84501], ],  Разность = 8602 >= 3221

Время выполнения: 0.167008876801 с

ОТВЕТ
Разброс = 3221
Группа: [
 0 => ["6"=>84501], 
 1 => ["9"=>81280], 
 2 => ["5"=>82350], 
 3 => ["8"=>82329], 
],
```

Результаты для k=8, n=100000 (краткий вывод, измеряем скорость):

```
Количество массивов: 8 Размерность массивов: 100000 Минимум = 100000 Максимум = 999996

Поиск группы элементов из разных подмассивов, имеющей наименьший разброс:

Разброс: 8 Группа: [ 0 => ["0"=>100012],  1 => ["1"=>100020],  2 => ["3"=>100014],  3 => ["2"=>100019],  4 => ["0"=>100013],  5 => ["2"=>100020],  6 => ["0"=>100017],  7 => ["1"=>100016], ], 

Разброс: 6 Группа: [ 0 => ["156"=>101445],  1 => ["152"=>101450],  2 => ["154"=>101446],  3 => ["153"=>101451],  4 => ["157"=>101448],  5 => ["169"=>101449],  6 => ["158"=>101449],  7 => ["143"=>101447], ], 

Разброс: 5 Группа: [ 0 => ["345"=>103088],  1 => ["354"=>103093],  2 => ["340"=>103092],  3 => ["346"=>103093],  4 => ["350"=>103092],  5 => ["353"=>103091],  6 => ["337"=>103091],  7 => ["330"=>103091], ], 

Разброс: 3 Группа: [ 0 => ["1202"=>110701],  1 => ["1201"=>110702],  2 => ["1175"=>110703],  3 => ["1159"=>110703],  4 => ["1236"=>110702],  5 => ["1196"=>110704],  6 => ["1207"=>110702],  7 => ["1187"=>110702], ], 

Разброс: 2 Группа: [ 0 => ["3841"=>134702],  1 => ["3777"=>134703],  2 => ["3833"=>134703],  3 => ["3809"=>134703],  4 => ["3916"=>134703],  5 => ["3840"=>134704],  6 => ["3734"=>134703],  7 => ["3903"=>134703], ], 

Время выполнения: 28.1246080399 с

ОТВЕТ
Разброс = 2
Группа: [
 0 => ["3841"=>134702], 
 1 => ["3777"=>134703], 
 2 => ["3833"=>134703], 
 3 => ["3809"=>134703], 
 4 => ["3916"=>134703], 
 5 => ["3840"=>134704], 
 6 => ["3734"=>134703], 
 7 => ["3903"=>134703], 
],
```